# HTML loses format when saved as file

Tags: html, css, web

I have created an html website using a web design site called "Nicepage"
when opening the site using the following link:

https://site117196.nicepage.io/?version=0736fec0-d4f8-437b-ba92-d3c0f375dffe&uid=8b00c2e9-4a6b-4ebe-9b14-75a068c57eb6

It seem to be working fin (let me know if it doesn't), it should look like this:

[image]

But when you save it as html and open it again it looses all of the design and looks like this:

[image]

I'm not very familiar with HTML/CSS, any information about why it happens will be welcomed.

Comment: My guess is because when you save as HTML to your machine, you are losing all of the links to the CSS and image files - the paths are most likely wrong. It looks like in the code all the script and link `src` points to `//...` Your computer is looking in your local files for `//` but that doesn't exist. Adding `https:` or `http` in front of those should fix it for you.

Comment: I don't know about others on this site, but I personally am _very_ reluctant to click away to some unknown third party URL posted in a question-- seems like a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="font-size: 16px;" lang="en"><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Graph based traceability analysis for the software development process, Connecting to neo4j, User side, Our Team">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>DevTracer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site117196.nicepage.io/nicepage.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site117196.nicepage.ioDevTracer.css" media="screen">
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="//capp.nicepage.com/assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" defer=""></script>
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="//capp.nicepage.com/01db292f7dec5dea9f984582599f825173540652/nicepage.js" defer=""></script>
    <meta name="generator" content="Nicepage 4.14.1, nicepage.com">
    <link id="u-theme-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i">
    <link id="u-page-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cambay:400,400i,700,700i">
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <script type="application/ld+json">{
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": ""
}</script>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#478ac9">
    <meta property="og:title" content="DevTracer">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  </head>
  <body data-home-page="https://site117196.nicepage.io/DevTracer.html" data-home-page-title="DevTracer" class="u-body u-xxl-mode" data-lang="en"><header class="u-clearfix u-header u-header" id="sec-14ab"><div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <h3 class="u-custom-font u-font-georgia u-headline u-text u-text-default u-text-palette-1-base u-text-1">
          <a href="/">Can't trace what you can't see</a>
        </h3>
        <h3 class="u-headline u-text u-text-default u-text-2">
          <a href="/"></a>
        </h3>
      </div></header>
    <section class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-white u-section-1" id="carousel_0e7a">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-valign-middle-sm u-valign-middle-xs u-sheet-1">
        <img class="u-image u-image-contain u-image-default u-image-1" alt="" data-image-width="1066" data-image-height="512" src="//images01.nicepage.com/2ff7d872d893fb8e3cb29142/f067b442161c5d4088585819/DevTracerLogo.png">
        <h2 class="u-custom-font u-font-georgia u-text u-text-default-lg u-text-default-md u-text-default-sm u-text-default-xl u-text-1">Graph based traceability analysis for the software development process</h2>
        <p class="u-custom-font u-font-georgia u-large-text u-text u-text-variant u-text-2">
          <span class="u-text-palette-1-base">Made by developers for developers</span>
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="u-clearfix u-section-2" id="sec-0e48">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <img class="u-image u-image-default u-image-1" src="//images01.nicepage.com/2ff7d872d893fb8e3cb29142/763598b1c7bb5c6bba003104/Screenshot_73.png" alt="" data-image-width="606" data-image-height="245">
        <div class="u-clearfix u-gutter-10 u-layout-wrap u-layout-wrap-1">
          <div class="u-layout">
            <div class="u-layout-row">
              <div class="u-size-60">
                <div class="u-layout-col">
                  <div class="u-border-no-bottom u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-container-style u-layout-cell u-right-cell u-size-60 u-layout-cell-1">
                    <div class="u-container-layout u-valign-top u-container-layout-1">
                      <p class="u-align-left u-custom-font u-font-georgia u-text u-text-palette-1-base u-text-1"> Graph database that stores and manages the data<br>&nbsp;in it's more natural and connected state.<br>It uses the classic vertecies and edges model<br>&nbsp;to maintain the relationships between different entities<br>and is a great tool to enable visualization options and meaningful outputs.&nbsp;
                      </p>
                      <a href="https://neo4j.com/" class="u-border-none u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u-hover-palette-1-light-1 u-palette-5-base u-radius-50 u-text-palette-1-base u-btn-1"><span class="u-icon"><svg class="u-svg-content" viewBox="0 0 53 53" x="0px" y="0px" style="width: 1em; height: 1em;"><path style="fill:#424A60;" d="M50.455,8L50.455,8C49.724,3.538,39.281,0,26.5,0S3.276,3.538,2.545,8l0,0H2.5v0.5V20v0.5V21v11v0.5
    V33v12h0.045c0.731,4.461,11.175,8,23.955,8s23.224-3.539,23.955-8H50.5V33v-0.5V32V21v-0.5V20V8.5V8H50.455z"></path><g><path style="fill:#424A60;" d="M26.5,41c-13.255,0-24-3.806-24-8.5V45h0.045c0.731,4.461,11.175,8,23.955,8s23.224-3.539,23.955-8
        H50.5V32.5C50.5,37.194,39.755,41,26.5,41z"></path><path style="fill:#424A60;" d="M2.5,32v0.5c0-0.168,0.018-0.334,0.045-0.5H2.5z"></path><path style="fill:#424A60;" d="M50.455,32c0.027,0.166,0.045,0.332,0.045,0.5V32H50.455z"></path>
</g><g><path style="fill:#556080;" d="M26.5,29c-13.255,0-24-3.806-24-8.5V33h0.045c0.731,4.461,11.175,8,23.955,8s23.224-3.539,23.955-8
        H50.5V20.5C50.5,25.194,39.755,29,26.5,29z"></path><path style="fill:#556080;" d="M2.5,20v0.5c0-0.168,0.018-0.334,0.045-0.5H2.5z"></path><path style="fill:#556080;" d="M50.455,20c0.027,0.166,0.045,0.332,0.045,0.5V20H50.455z"></path>
</g><ellipse style="fill:#7FABDA;" cx="26.5" cy="8.5" rx="24" ry="8.5"></ellipse><g><path style="fill:#7383BF;" d="M26.5,17c-13.255,0-24-3.806-24-8.5V21h0.045c0.731,4.461,11.175,8,23.955,8s23.224-3.539,23.955-8
        H50.5V8.5C50.5,13.194,39.755,17,26.5,17z"></path><path style="fill:#7383BF;" d="M2.5,8v0.5c0-0.168,0.018-0.334,0.045-0.5H2.5z"></path><path style="fill:#7383BF;" d="M50.455,8C50.482,8.166,50.5,8.332,50.5,8.5V8H50.455z"></path>
</g></svg><img></span>&nbsp;Read more
                      </a>
                      <h4 class="u-align-center u-custom-font u-font-georgia u-text u-text-palette-1-base u-text-2">Our project uses neo4j to store all the entities and their connections to each other<br>in the code development process.
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-section-3" id="sec-ca9e">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-valign-middle u-sheet-1">
        <div class="u-clearfix u-expanded-width u-gutter-0 u-layout-wrap u-layout-wrap-1">
          <div class="u-layout" style="">
            <div class="u-layout-row" style="">
              <div class="u-align-left u-container-style u-image u-layout-cell u-left-cell u-size-30 u-size-xs-60 u-image-1" src="" data-image-width="918" data-image-height="662">
                <div class="u-container-layout u-valign-middle u-container-layout-1" src=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="u-align-left u-container-style u-layout-cell u-palette-1-base u-right-cell u-size-30 u-size-xs-60 u-layout-cell-2">
                <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-2">
                  <h2 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-white u-text-1"> Connecting to neo4j</h2>
                  <p class="u-custom-font u-font-georgia u-text u-text-2">We used python API in order to connect to the database and send queries to it.<br>We also researched and found a visualization script that displays the results of the queries.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-section-4" id="sec-35df">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <div class="u-clearfix u-gutter-0 u-layout-wrap u-layout-wrap-1">
          <div class="u-layout" style="">
            <div class="u-layout-row" style="">
              <div class="u-align-left u-container-style u-layout-cell u-left-cell u-size-30 u-size-xs-60 u-white u-layout-cell-1" src="">
                <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-1">
                  <h2 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-1"> User side</h2>
                  <p class="u-custom-font u-font-georgia u-text u-text-2"> Our package provides the user with a base of quries that he can use.<br>The user can add his own queries in a generic way and decides whether he wants to receive a visual output.<br>The connection to the database is transparent to the user.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="u-align-left u-container-style u-image u-layout-cell u-right-cell u-size-30 u-size-xs-60 u-image-1" data-image-width="862" data-image-height="882">
                <div class="u-container-layout u-valign-middle u-container-layout-2" src=""></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="u-clearfix u-section-5" id="sec-70ba">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-valign-middle u-sheet-1">
        <a href="https://github.com/shalevv123/DevTracer" class="u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-palette-5-base u-btn-1"><span class="u-file-icon u-icon"><img src="//images01.nicepage.com/2ff7d872d893fb8e3cb29142/6af8ce84a9fd594183629deb/148798.png" alt=""></span>&nbsp;Git Repository&nbsp; 
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-grey-10 u-section-6" id="sec-471a">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <h2 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-1">Our Team</h2>
        <p class="u-text u-text-2">Third year computer science students at the Technion were joined together with Elbit Systems in an industrial project course to create this project</p>
        <div class="u-expanded-width-lg u-expanded-width-xl u-expanded-width-xs u-list u-list-1">
          <div class="u-repeater u-repeater-1">
            <div class="u-align-center u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-valign-bottom-xs u-container-layout-1">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-3">Ori Arad&nbsp;</h5>
                <p class="u-text u-text-4">Elbit Systems software engineer<br>Industrial supervisor
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-align-center u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-valign-bottom-xs u-container-layout-2">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-5">Shalev Rissin</h5>
                <p class="u-text u-text-6">Software Engineering student<br>Developer
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-align-center u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-valign-bottom-xs u-container-layout-3">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-7">Ariel Kizner</h5>
                <p class="u-text u-text-8">Computer Science student<br>Developer
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <footer class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-footer u-palette-5-base u-footer" id="sec-c72b"><div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <p class="u-small-text u-text u-text-variant u-text-1">We really enjoyed making this project and we hope you also enjoy using it&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      </div></footer>
    <section class="u-backlink u-clearfix u-grey-80">
      <a class="u-link" href="https://nicepage.com/website-templates" target="_blank">
        <span>Website Templates</span>
      </a>
      <p class="u-text">
        <span>created with</span>
      </p>
      <a class="u-link" href="" target="_blank">
        <span>Website Builder Software</span>
      </a>. 
    </section>
  
</body></html>
```

You have to change all of the local files in the code to have them link directly to the site since you aren't hosting them.

Answer (score -1):

Check your css links , you can also use your browser console to check if it is loading the css files properly.